# BootStrap navbar Toggle not working in asp.net

Tags: jquery, asp.net, css, c#-4.0, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a page (ASP.NET Web Forms) using bootstrap 3.0.
The menu is on the master page:

```
                <div class="navbar-header">
                <!-- BEGIN RESPONSIVE MENU TOGGLER -->
                <button class="navbar-toggle btn navbar-btn" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <!-- END RESPONSIVE MENU TOGGLER -->
                <!-- BEGIN LOGO -->
                <a class="navbar-brand logo-v1" href="/">
                    <div class="">
                        <img src="img/logo//ITT_logo_horizontal_blue_large.png" id="Img1" alt="Iceland Taxi Tours Logo" width="330" />
                    </div>
                </a>
                <!-- END LOGO -->
            </div>

            <!-- BEGIN TOP NAVIGATION MENU -->
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li runat="server" id="lnkHome" class="active">
                        <a runat="server" href="/">Home
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li runat="server" id="lnkTours" class="dropdown">
                        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" data-hover="dropdown" data-delay="0" data-close-others="false" href="#">Tours
                        <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i>
                        </a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li>
                                <asp:LinkButton ID="btnDayTours" runat="server" OnClick="btnDayTours_Click">Day Tours</asp:LinkButton></li>
                            <li>
                                <asp:LinkButton ID="btnLongTours" runat="server" OnClick="btnLongTours_Click">Longer Tours</asp:LinkButton></li>
                            <li><a runat="server" href="tours">View All Tours</a></li>
                            <li><a href="customize_your_tour">Customized Tour</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li runat="server" id="lnkSights" class="dropdown">
                        <a class="dropdown-toggle" href="keflavik_airport_transfer">Airport Transfer</a>
                    </li>
                    <li runat="server" id="lnkBlueLagoon" class="dropdown">
                        <a class="dropdown-toggle" href="blue_lagoon_tours">Blue Lagoon</a>
                    </li>
                    <li runat="server" id="lnkOtherServices" class="dropdown">
                        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" data-hover="dropdown" data-delay="0" data-close-others="false" href="#">Other Services
                        <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i>
                        </a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">

                            <li><a runat="server" href="cruise_ship_services">Cruise Ship Services</a></li>
                            <li><a href="handicapped_services">Handicapped Services</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li runat="server" id="lnkAbout"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" data-hover="dropdown" data-delay="0" data-close-others="false" href="#">About
                    <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i>
                    </a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a runat="server" href="about">About Us</a></li>
                            <li><a runat="server" href="contact">Contact Us</a></li>
                            <li><a href="faq" runat="server">FAQ</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <%--       <li class="menu-search">
                        <span class="sep"></span>
                        <i class="fa fa-search search-btn"></i>
                        <div class="search-box">
                            <div>
                                <div class="input-group input-large">
                                    <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Search">
                                    <span class="input-group-btn">
                                        <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnSearch" class="btn theme-btn" Text="Go" ToolTip="Search the site" />
                                    </span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </li>--%>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- BEGIN TOP NAVIGATION MENU -->
```

if I set display: block !important; on class: .header .navbar-collapse is shown ...all the time.

When i press the toggle button the page does a full post back every time and the "menu" stays open during Page_Load ....than is closed again.

You haev a live version out there if you like to take a look: http://www.icelandtaxitours.is

Any ideas?

Comment: uuhhh well...problem solved. changed <button> to <div> ...no post back :D